# Facebook and Admob Rewarded Video SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, admob

I have developed this game 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egames.planetdefender

The Facebook leader board and AdMob Rewarded Video not working for me every time , some time it work . some time sends error

Can you share me good example of both integration or with what should I be careful for same ?

Thank You & Regards,
Nidhi Kakadiya

Comment: Can you put some of code and what kind of error you are getting in LogCat?

Comment: `some time sends error` ?  which type of error, show your logout error output